# Importing Packages in Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I try and import `BeautifulSoup` into `IPython Notebook` I get an error message: `ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup`. The package is installed and works perfectly in IDLE. When I check system version, it returns `2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.7.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:37:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`. This would seem to be the same version of python I run in IDLE, though minus the Anaconda. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what is the output of `import sys; sys.executable` ... .in both IDLE and ipython notebook?

Comment: C:\Anaconda\python.exe in IPython vs C:\Python27\pythonw.exe in IDLE. How do I change it in Ipython?

Comment: install ipython in your IDLE's python or make anaconda's python as a default python. ..

Comment: It is installed within the Python27 folder with this installer http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython Do you know how to change default in IPython? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: delete the "C:\Python27" and "C:\Python27\scripts\" path from windows's path . .  and add new path "C:\Anaconda" and "C:\Anaconda\scripts" in the system path. . .

Comment: That would run the Anaconda version, not the standard version. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Anaconda is a free collection of powerful packages for Python that enables large-scale data management, analysis, and visualization for Business Intelligence, Scientific Analysis, Engineering, Machine Learning, and more.. .so forget the standard version. . use anaconda's python.. . here is a list of packages that are included in anacoda. . http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers to your question.  If you have no need for running multiple copies of Python running different modules, you can simply change all instances of the string "Python27" in your `PATH` to "Anaconda" (assuming you want to run the Anaconda Python) as suggested in the comments.

Alternately, if you want to run different combinations of modules in two copies of the same version of Python, you can segregate/partition the modules you install into Anaconda/default Python versions.  If you install using Windows installer, just make sure both versions of Python are in the registry (they should be by default) and the install wizard should allow you to choose where you want to install it.  You can also individually install modules from their source code, adding them to `"C:\Python27\Lib"` or `"C:\Anaconda\Lib"` depending on the environment in which you want to use them.